# Redshift: Substitute WHERE IN with WITH () and JOIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, with-statement

```sql
WITH temp_table(id)
??? INSERT INTO ??? VALUES (
  ('a'),
  ('b'),
  ('c')
)
SELECT * from real_data rd
JOIN rd.id = temp_table.id;
```

Please help me out how to write an SQL statement **for Redshift** which includes a preliminary temp table definition where I can define multiple rows of constants, that I can use to join with real tables and select multiple matching rows.

My goal is to do a `SELECT WHERE IN` but more efficiently. Is 'WHERE IN' good enough with 5 values? With 10, with 100?

Comment: If you want optimal performance, then use a formal table with indices rather than an inline CTE.

Comment: You can put a huge quantity of values in a `WHERE x IN (...)` statement.

Comment: is `WHERE IN` as efficient as a `JOIN` would be?